# Some problem about"JDK.nashorn" ，error:Failed generating bytecode for <eval>:1

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

I used JavaScript Enginne to calculate a lot of data in my application, used JDK.nashorn .But sometime, in some problems in server environment. Not often.

JDK version:1.8.0_144
OS:CentOS 7.4, 64bit
JVM config: java -Xmx512m -Xms1024m
I tried to used "java -Xmx1024m -Xms2048m", but it not worked.

JS script  code:

```
function temp(){ var _1001YE=0,_1002YE=0,_1012YE=0,_1001NCS=0,_1002NCS=0,_1012NCS=0,_1101YE=0,_1431YE=0,_1101NCS=0,_1431NCS=0,_1121YE=0,_1121NCS=0,_1122YE=0,_1231YE=0,_1122NCS=0,_1231NCS=0,_1123YE=0,_1123NCS=0,_1131YE=0,_1132YE=0,_1221YE=0,_1131NCS=0,_1132NCS=0,_1221NCS=0,_1401YE=0,_1402YE=0,_1403YE=0,_1404YE=0,_1405YE=0,_1406YE=0,_1407YE=0,_1408YE=0,_1411YE=0,_1421YE=0,_1461YE=0,_1471YE=0,_5001YE=0,_5101YE=0,_5201YE=0,_5401YE=0,_5402YE=0,_5403YE=0,_1321YE=0,_2314YE=0,_1401NCS=0,_1402NCS=0,_1403NCS=0,_1404NCS=0,_1405NCS=0,_1406NCS=0,_1407NCS=0,_1408NCS=0,_1411NCS=0,_1421NCS=0,_1461NCS=0,_1471NCS=0,_5001NCS=0,_5101NCS=0,_5201NCS=0,_5401NCS=0,_5402NCS=0,_5403NCS=0,_1321NCS=0,_2314NCS=0,_190101YE=0,_1451YE=0,_190101NCS=0,_1451NCS=0,_1503YE=0,_1503NCS=0,_1501YE=0,_1502YE=0,_1501NCS=0,_1502NCS=0,_1531YE=0,_1611YE=0,_1532YE=0,_1531NCS=0,_1611NCS=0,_1532NCS=0,_1511YE=0,_1512YE=0,_1511NCS=0,_1512NCS=0,_1521YE=0,_1521NCS=0,_1601YE=0,_1602YE=0,_1603YE=0,_1606YE=0,_1601NCS=0,_1602NCS=0,_1603NCS=0,_1606NCS=0,_1604YE=0,_1605YE=0,_1604NCS=0,_1605NCS=0,_1621YE=0,_1622YE=0,_1621NCS=0,_1622NCS=0,_1631YE=0,_1632YE=0,_1631NCS=0,_1632NCS=0,_1701YE=0,_1702YE=0,_1703YE=0,_1701NCS=0,_1702NCS=0,_1703NCS=0,_530102YE=0,_530102NCS=0,_1711YE=0,_1711NCS=0,_1801YE=0,_1801NCS=0,_1811YE=0,_1811NCS=0,_190102YE=0,_1623YE=0,_1441YE=0,_190102NCS=0,_1623NCS=0,_1441NCS=0,_2001YE=0,_2001NCS=0,_2101YE=0,_2101NCS=0,_2201YE=0,_2201NCS=0,_2202YE=0,_1123DFYE=0,_2202NCS=0,_1123DFNCS=0,_2203YE=0,_2203NCS=0,_2211YE=0,_2211NCS=0,_2221YE=0,_2221NCS=0,_2231YE=0,_2232YE=0,_2241YE=0,_2231NCS=0,_2232NCS=0,_2241NCS=0,_2501YE=0,_2501NCS=0,_2502YE=0,_2502NCS=0,_2701YE=0,_2702YE=0,_2711YE=0,_2701NCS=0,_2702NCS=0,_2711NCS=0,_2801YE=0,_2801NCS=0,_2401YE=0,_2401NCS=0,_2901YE=0,_2901NCS=0,_4001YE=0,_4001NCS=0,_4002YE=0,_4002NCS=0,_4201YE=0,_4201NCS=0,_4101YE=0,_4101NCS=0,_4103YE=0,_4104YE=0,_4103NCS=0,_4104NCS=0, apart = 0 ;_1001YE = 2481701100,_1001JFYE = 2481701100,_1001DFYE = 0,_1001NCS = 2481701100,_1002YE = 322529100,_1002JFYE = 322529100,_1002DFYE = 0,_1002NCS = 322529100,_1012YE = 0,_1012JFYE = 0,_1012DFYE = 0,_1012NCS = 0,_1101YE = 0,_1101JFYE = 0,_1101DFYE = 0,_1101NCS = 0,_1121YE = 0,_1121JFYE = 0,_1121DFYE = 0,_1121NCS = 0,_1122YE = 2680419100,_1122JFYE = 2680419100,_1122DFYE = 0,_1122NCS = 2680419100,_1123YE = 0,_1123JFYE = 0,_1123DFYE = 0,_1123NCS = 0,_1131YE = 0,_1131JFYE = 0,_1131DFYE = 0,_1131NCS = 0,_1132YE = 0,_1132JFYE = 0,_1132DFYE = 0,_1132NCS = 0,_1221YE = 0,_1221JFYE = 0,_1221DFYE = 0,_1221NCS = 0,_1231YE = 0,_1231JFYE = 0,_1231DFYE = 0,_1231NCS = 0,_1321YE = 0,_1321JFYE = 0,_1321DFYE = 0,_1321NCS = 0,_1401YE = 0,_1401JFYE = 0,_1401DFYE = 0,_1401NCS = 0,_1402YE = 0,_1402JFYE = 0,_1402DFYE = 0,_1402NCS = 0,_1403YE = 0,_1403JFYE = 0,_1403DFYE = 0,_1403NCS = 0,_1404YE = 0,_1404JFYE = 0,_1404DFYE = 0,_1404NCS = 0,_1405YE = 874024000,_1405JFYE = 874024000,_1405DFYE = 0,_1405NCS = 874024000,_1406YE = 0,_1406JFYE = 0,_1406DFYE = 0,_1406NCS = 0,_1407YE = 0,_1407JFYE = 0,_1407DFYE = 0,_1407NCS = 0,_1408YE = 0,_1408JFYE = 0,_1408DFYE = 0,_1408NCS = 0,_1411YE = 0,_1411JFYE = 0,_1411DFYE = 0,_1411NCS = 0,_1471YE = 0,_1471JFYE = 0,_1471DFYE = 0,_1471NCS = 0,_1501YE = 0,_1501JFYE = 0,_1501DFYE = 0,_1501NCS = 0,_1502YE = 0,_1502JFYE = 0,_1502DFYE = 0,_1502NCS = 0,_1503YE = 0,_1503JFYE = 0,_1503DFYE = 0,_1503NCS = 0,_1511YE = 0,_1511JFYE = 0,_1511DFYE = 0,_1511NCS = 0,_1512YE = 0,_1512JFYE = 0,_1512DFYE = 0,_1512NCS = 0,_1521YE = 0,_1521JFYE = 0,_1521DFYE = 0,_1521NCS = 0,_1531YE = 0,_1531JFYE = 0,_1531DFYE = 0,_1531NCS = 0,_1532YE = 0,_1532JFYE = 0,_1532DFYE = 0,_1532NCS = 0,_1601YE = 406187400,_1601JFYE = 406187400,_1601DFYE = 0,_1601NCS = 406187400,_1602YE = 71197200,_1602JFYE = 0,_1602DFYE = 71197200,_1602NCS = 71197200,_1603YE = 0,_1603JFYE = 0,_1603DFYE = 0,_1603NCS = 0,_1604YE = 0,_1604JFYE = 0,_1604DFYE = 0,_1604NCS = 0,_1605YE = 0,_1605JFYE = 0,_1605DFYE = 0,_1605NCS = 0,_1606YE = 0,_1606JFYE = 0,_1606DFYE = 0,_1606NCS = 0,_1611YE = 0,_1611JFYE = 0,_1611DFYE = 0,_1611NCS = 0,_1621YE = 0,_1621JFYE = 0,_1621DFYE = 0,_1621NCS = 0,_1622YE = 0,_1622JFYE = 0,_1622DFYE = 0,_1622NCS = 0,_1623YE = 0,_1623JFYE = 0,_1623DFYE = 0,_1623NCS = 0,_1631YE = 0,_1631JFYE = 0,_1631DFYE = 0,_1631NCS = 0,_1632YE = 0,_1632JFYE = 0,_1632DFYE = 0,_1632NCS = 0,_1701YE = 0,_1701JFYE = 0,_1701DFYE = 0,_1701NCS = 0,_1702YE = 0,_1702JFYE = 0,_1702DFYE = 0,_1702NCS = 0,_1703YE = 0,_1703JFYE = 0,_1703DFYE = 0,_1703NCS = 0,_1711YE = 0,_1711JFYE = 0,_1711DFYE = 0,_1711NCS = 0,_1801YE = 0,_1801JFYE = 0,_1801DFYE = 0,_1801NCS = 0,_1811YE = 0,_1811JFYE = 0,_1811DFYE = 0,_1811NCS = 0,_190101YE = 0,_190101JFYE = 0,_190101DFYE = 0,_190101NCS = 0,_190102YE = 0,_190102JFYE = 0,_190102DFYE = 0,_190102NCS = 0,_2001YE = 0,_2001JFYE = 0,_2001DFYE = 0,_2001NCS = 0,_2101YE = 0,_2101JFYE = 0,_2101DFYE = 0,_2101NCS = 0,_2201YE = 0,_2201JFYE = 0,_2201DFYE = 0,_2201NCS = 0,_2202YE = 4306782800,_2202JFYE = 0,_2202DFYE = 4306782800,_2202NCS = 4306782800,_2203YE = 0,_2203JFYE = 0,_2203DFYE = 0,_2203NCS = 0,_2211YE = 0,_2211JFYE = 0,_2211DFYE = 0,_2211NCS = 0,_2221YE = 452900,_2221JFYE = 0,_2221DFYE = 452900,_2221NCS = 452900,_2231YE = 0,_2231JFYE = 0,_2231DFYE = 0,_2231NCS = 0,_2232YE = 0,_2232JFYE = 0,_2232DFYE = 0,_2232NCS = 0,_2241YE = -4234740000,_2241JFYE = 0,_2241DFYE = -4234740000,_2241NCS = -4234740000,_2314YE = 0,_2314JFYE = 0,_2314DFYE = 0,_2314NCS = 0,_2401YE = 0,_2401JFYE = 0,_2401DFYE = 0,_2401NCS = 0,_2501YE = 0,_2501JFYE = 0,_2501DFYE = 0,_2501NCS = 0,_2502YE = 0,_2502JFYE = 0,_2502DFYE = 0,_2502NCS = 0,_2701YE = 0,_2701JFYE = 0,_2701DFYE = 0,_2701NCS = 0,_2702YE = 0,_2702JFYE = 0,_2702DFYE = 0,_2702NCS = 0,_2711YE = 0,_2711JFYE = 0,_2711DFYE = 0,_2711NCS = 0,_2801YE = 0,_2801JFYE = 0,_2801DFYE = 0,_2801NCS = 0,_2901YE = 0,_2901JFYE = 0,_2901DFYE = 0,_2901NCS = 0,_4001YE = 7868390000,_4001JFYE = 0,_4001DFYE = 7868390000,_4001NCS = 7868390000,_4002YE = 0,_4002JFYE = 0,_4002DFYE = 0,_4002NCS = 0,_4101YE = 0,_4101JFYE = 0,_4101DFYE = 0,_4101NCS = 0,_4103YE = 0,_4103JFYE = 0,_4103DFYE = 0,_4103NCS = 0,_4104YE = -1247222200,_4104JFYE = 0,_4104DFYE = -1247222200,_4104NCS = -1247222200,_4201YE = 0,_4201JFYE = 0,_4201DFYE = 0,_4201NCS = 0,_5001YE = 0,_5001JFYE = 0,_5001DFYE = 0,_5001NCS = 0,_5101YE = 0,_5101JFYE = 0,_5101DFYE = 0,_5101NCS = 0,_5201YE = 0,_5201JFYE = 0,_5201DFYE = 0,_5201NCS = 0,_530102YE = 0,_530102JFYE = 0,_530102DFYE = 0,_530102NCS = 0,_5401YE = 0,_5401JFYE = 0,_5401DFYE = 0,_5401NCS = 0,_5402YE = 0,_5402JFYE = 0,_5402DFYE = 0,_5402NCS = 0,_5403YE = 0,_5403JFYE = 0,_5403DFYE = 0,_5403NCS = 0, temp=0; var  atemp = {}; var H1 = _1001YE+_1002YE+_1012YE; atemp['H1'] = _1001YE+_1002YE+_1012YE; var HNCS1 = _1001NCS+_1002NCS+_1012NCS; atemp['HNCS1'] = _1001NCS+_1002NCS+_1012NCS; var H2 = _1101YE+_1431YE; atemp['H2'] = _1101YE+_1431YE; var HNCS2 = _1101NCS+_1431NCS; atemp['HNCS2'] = _1101NCS+_1431NCS; var H3 = 0; atemp['H3'] = 0; var HNCS3 = 0; atemp['HNCS3'] = 0; var H4 = _1121YE; atemp['H4'] = _1121YE; var HNCS4 = _1121NCS; atemp['HNCS4'] = _1121NCS; var H5 = _1122YE-_1231YE; atemp['H5'] = _1122YE-_1231YE; var HNCS5 = _1122NCS-_1231NCS; atemp['HNCS5'] = _1122NCS-_1231NCS; var H6 = _1123YE; atemp['H6'] = _1123YE; var HNCS6 = _1123NCS; atemp['HNCS6'] = _1123NCS; var H7 = _1131YE+_1132YE+_1221YE; atemp['H7'] = _1131YE+_1132YE+_1221YE; var HNCS7 = _1131NCS+_1132NCS+_1221NCS; atemp['HNCS7'] = _1131NCS+_1132NCS+_1221NCS; var H8 = _1401YE+_1402YE+_1403YE+_1404YE+_1405YE+_1406YE-_1407YE+_1408YE+_1411YE+_1421YE+_1461YE-_1471YE+_5001YE+_5101YE+_5201YE+_5401YE+_5402YE+_5403YE+_1321YE-_2314YE; atemp['H8'] = _1401YE+_1402YE+_1403YE+_1404YE+_1405YE+_1406YE-_1407YE+_1408YE+_1411YE+_1421YE+_1461YE-_1471YE+_5001YE+_5101YE+_5201YE+_5401YE+_5402YE+_5403YE+_1321YE-_2314YE; var HNCS8 = _1401NCS+_1402NCS+_1403NCS+_1404NCS+_1405NCS+_1406NCS-_1407NCS+_1408NCS+_1411NCS+_1421NCS+_1461NCS-_1471NCS+_5001NCS+_5101NCS+_5201NCS+_5401NCS+_5402NCS+_5403NCS+_1321NCS-_2314NCS; atemp['HNCS8'] = _1401NCS+_1402NCS+_1403NCS+_1404NCS+_1405NCS+_1406NCS-_1407NCS+_1408NCS+_1411NCS+_1421NCS+_1461NCS-_1471NCS+_5001NCS+_5101NCS+_5201NCS+_5401NCS+_5402NCS+_5403NCS+_1321NCS-_2314NCS; var H9 = 0; atemp['H9'] = 0; var HNCS9 = 0; atemp['HNCS9'] = 0; var H10 = 0; atemp['H10'] = 0; var HNCS10 = 0; atemp['HNCS10'] = 0; var H11 = _190101YE+_1451YE; atemp['H11'] = _190101YE+_1451YE; var HNCS11 = _190101NCS+_1451NCS; atemp['HNCS11'] = _190101NCS+_1451NCS; var H13 = 0; atemp['H13'] = 0; var HNCS13 = 0; atemp['HNCS13'] = 0; var H14 = _1503YE; atemp['H14'] = _1503YE; var HNCS14 = _1503NCS; atemp['HNCS14'] = _1503NCS; var H15 = _1501YE-_1502YE; atemp['H15'] = _1501YE-_1502YE; var HNCS15 = _1501NCS-_1502NCS; atemp['HNCS15'] = _1501NCS-_1502NCS; var H16 = _1531YE+_1611YE-_1532YE; atemp['H16'] = _1531YE+_1611YE-_1532YE; var HNCS16 = _1531NCS+_1611NCS-_1532NCS; atemp['HNCS16'] = _1531NCS+_1611NCS-_1532NCS; var H17 = _1511YE-_1512YE; atemp['H17'] = _1511YE-_1512YE; var HNCS17 = _1511NCS-_1512NCS; atemp['HNCS17'] = _1511NCS-_1512NCS; var H18 = _1521YE; atemp['H18'] = _1521YE; var HNCS18 = _1521NCS; atemp['HNCS18'] = _1521NCS; var H19 = _1601YE-_1602YE-_1603YE+_1606YE; atemp['H19'] = _1601YE-_1602YE-_1603YE+_1606YE; var HNCS19 = _1601NCS-_1602NCS-_1603NCS+_1606NCS; atemp['HNCS19'] = _1601NCS-_1602NCS-_1603NCS+_1606NCS; var H20 = _1604YE+_1605YE; atemp['H20'] = _1604YE+_1605YE; var HNCS20 = _1604NCS+_1605NCS; atemp['HNCS20'] = _1604NCS+_1605NCS; var H21 = _1621YE-_1622YE; atemp['H21'] = _1621YE-_1622YE; var HNCS21 = _1621NCS-_1622NCS; atemp['HNCS21'] = _1621NCS-_1622NCS; var H22 = _1631YE-_1632YE; atemp['H22'] = _1631YE-_1632YE; var HNCS22 = _1631NCS-_1632NCS; atemp['HNCS22'] = _1631NCS-_1632NCS; var H23 = _1701YE-_1702YE-_1703YE; atemp['H23'] = _1701YE-_1702YE-_1703YE; var HNCS23 = _1701NCS-_1702NCS-_1703NCS; atemp['HNCS23'] = _1701NCS-_1702NCS-_1703NCS; var H24 = _530102YE; atemp['H24'] = _530102YE; var HNCS24 = _530102NCS; atemp['HNCS24'] = _530102NCS; var H25 = _1711YE; atemp['H25'] = _1711YE; var HNCS25 = _1711NCS; atemp['HNCS25'] = _1711NCS; var H26 = _1801YE; atemp['H26'] = _1801YE; var HNCS26 = _1801NCS; atemp['HNCS26'] = _1801NCS; var H27 = _1811YE; atemp['H27'] = _1811YE; var HNCS27 = _1811NCS; atemp['HNCS27'] = _1811NCS; var H28 = _190102YE+_1623YE+_1441YE; atemp['H28'] = _190102YE+_1623YE+_1441YE; var HNCS28 = _190102NCS+_1623NCS+_1441NCS; atemp['HNCS28'] = _190102NCS+_1623NCS+_1441NCS; var H31 = 0; atemp['H31'] = 0; var HNCS31 = 0; atemp['HNCS31'] = 0; var H32 = _2001YE; atemp['H32'] = _2001YE; var HNCS32 = _2001NCS; atemp['HNCS32'] = _2001NCS; var H33 = _2101YE; atemp['H33'] = _2101YE; var HNCS33 = _2101NCS; atemp['HNCS33'] = _2101NCS; var H34 = 0; atemp['H34'] = 0; var HNCS34 = 0; atemp['HNCS34'] = 0; var H35 = _2201YE; atemp['H35'] = _2201YE; var HNCS35 = _2201NCS; atemp['HNCS35'] = _2201NCS; var H36 = _2202YE+_1123DFYE; atemp['H36'] = _2202YE+_1123DFYE; var HNCS36 = _2202NCS+_1123DFNCS; atemp['HNCS36'] = _2202NCS+_1123DFNCS; var H37 = _2203YE; atemp['H37'] = _2203YE; var HNCS37 = _2203NCS; atemp['HNCS37'] = _2203NCS; var H38 = _2211YE; atemp['H38'] = _2211YE; var HNCS38 = _2211NCS; atemp['HNCS38'] = _2211NCS; var H39 = _2221YE; atemp['H39'] = _2221YE; var HNCS39 = _2221NCS; atemp['HNCS39'] = _2221NCS; var H40 = _2231YE+_2232YE+_2241YE; atemp['H40'] = _2231YE+_2232YE+_2241YE; var HNCS40 = _2231NCS+_2232NCS+_2241NCS; atemp['HNCS40'] = _2231NCS+_2232NCS+_2241NCS; var H41 = 0; atemp['H41'] = 0; var HNCS41 = 0; atemp['HNCS41'] = 0; var H42 = 0; atemp['H42'] = 0; var HNCS42 = 0; atemp['HNCS42'] = 0; var H43 = 0; atemp['H43'] = 0; var HNCS43 = 0; atemp['HNCS43'] = 0; var H45 = 0; atemp['H45'] = 0; var HNCS45 = 0; atemp['HNCS45'] = 0; var H46 = _2501YE; atemp['H46'] = _2501YE; var HNCS46 = _2501NCS; atemp['HNCS46'] = _2501NCS; var H47 = _2502YE; atemp['H47'] = _2502YE; var HNCS47 = _2502NCS; atemp['HNCS47'] = _2502NCS; var H48 = 0; atemp['H48'] = 0; var HNCS48 = 0; atemp['HNCS48'] = 0; var H49 = 0; atemp['H49'] = 0; var HNCS49 = 0; atemp['HNCS49'] = 0; var H50 = _2701YE-_2702YE+_2711YE; atemp['H50'] = _2701YE-_2702YE+_2711YE; var HNCS50 = _2701NCS-_2702NCS+_2711NCS; atemp['HNCS50'] = _2701NCS-_2702NCS+_2711NCS; var H51 = _2801YE; atemp['H51'] = _2801YE; var HNCS51 = _2801NCS; atemp['HNCS51'] = _2801NCS; var H52 = _2401YE; atemp['H52'] = _2401YE; var HNCS52 = _2401NCS; atemp['HNCS52'] = _2401NCS; var H53 = _2901YE; atemp['H53'] = _2901YE; var HNCS53 = _2901NCS; atemp['HNCS53'] = _2901NCS; var H54 = 0; atemp['H54'] = 0; var HNCS54 = 0; atemp['HNCS54'] = 0; var H57 = 0; atemp['H57'] = 0; var HNCS57 = 0; atemp['HNCS57'] = 0; var H58 = _4001YE; atemp['H58'] = _4001YE; var HNCS58 = _4001NCS; atemp['HNCS58'] = _4001NCS; var H59 = 0; atemp['H59'] = 0; var HNCS59 = 0; atemp['HNCS59'] = 0; var H60 = 0; atemp['H60'] = 0; var HNCS60 = 0; atemp['HNCS60'] = 0; var H61 = 0; atemp['H61'] = 0; var HNCS61 = 0; atemp['HNCS61'] = 0; var H62 = _4002YE; atemp['H62'] = _4002YE; var HNCS62 = _4002NCS; atemp['HNCS62'] = _4002NCS; var H63 = _4201YE; atemp['H63'] = _4201YE; var HNCS63 = _4201NCS; atemp['HNCS63'] = _4201NCS; var H64 = 0; atemp['H64'] = 0; var HNCS64 = 0; atemp['HNCS64'] = 0; var H65 = 0; atemp['H65'] = 0; var HNCS65 = 0; atemp['HNCS65'] = 0; var H66 = _4101YE; atemp['H66'] = _4101YE; var HNCS66 = _4101NCS; atemp['HNCS66'] = _4101NCS; var H67 = _4103YE+_4104YE; atemp['H67'] = _4103YE+_4104YE; var HNCS67 = _4103NCS+_4104NCS; atemp['HNCS67'] = _4103NCS+_4104NCS; var H12 = H1+H2+H3+H4+H5+H6+H7+H8+H9+H10+H11; atemp['H12'] = H1+H2+H3+H4+H5+H6+H7+H8+H9+H10+H11; var HNCS12 = HNCS1+HNCS2+HNCS3+HNCS4+HNCS5+HNCS6+HNCS7+HNCS8+HNCS9+HNCS10+HNCS11; atemp['HNCS12'] = HNCS1+HNCS2+HNCS3+HNCS4+HNCS5+HNCS6+HNCS7+HNCS8+HNCS9+HNCS10+HNCS11; var H29 = H14+H15+H16+H17+H18+H19+H20+H21+H22+H23+H24+H25+H26+H27+H28; atemp['H29'] = H14+H15+H16+H17+H18+H19+H20+H21+H22+H23+H24+H25+H26+H27+H28; var HNCS29 = HNCS14+HNCS15+HNCS16+HNCS17+HNCS18+HNCS19+HNCS20+HNCS21+HNCS22+HNCS23+HNCS24+HNCS25+HNCS26+HNCS27+HNCS28; atemp['HNCS29'] = HNCS14+HNCS15+HNCS16+HNCS17+HNCS18+HNCS19+HNCS20+HNCS21+HNCS22+HNCS23+HNCS24+HNCS25+HNCS26+HNCS27+HNCS28; var H30 = H12+H29; atemp['H30'] = H12+H29; var HNCS30 = HNCS12+HNCS29; atemp['HNCS30'] = HNCS12+HNCS29; var H44 = H32+H33+H34+H35+H36+H37+H38+H39+H40+H41+H42+H43; atemp['H44'] = H32+H33+H34+H35+H36+H37+H38+H39+H40+H41+H42+H43; var HNCS44 = HNCS32+HNCS33+HNCS34+HNCS35+HNCS36+HNCS37+HNCS38+HNCS39+HNCS40+HNCS41+HNCS42+HNCS43; atemp['HNCS44'] = HNCS32+HNCS33+HNCS34+HNCS35+HNCS36+HNCS37+HNCS38+HNCS39+HNCS40+HNCS41+HNCS42+HNCS43; var H55 = H45+H46+H47+H50+H51+H52+H53+H54; atemp['H55'] = H45+H46+H47+H50+H51+H52+H53+H54; var HNCS55 = HNCS45+HNCS46+HNCS47+HNCS50+HNCS51+HNCS52+HNCS53+HNCS54; atemp['HNCS55'] = HNCS45+HNCS46+HNCS47+HNCS50+HNCS51+HNCS52+HNCS53+HNCS54; var H56 = H44+H55; atemp['H56'] = H44+H55; var HNCS56 = HNCS44+HNCS55; atemp['HNCS56'] = HNCS44+HNCS55; var H68 = H58+H59+H62-H63+H64+H65+H66+H67; atemp['H68'] = H58+H59+H62-H63+H64+H65+H66+H67; var HNCS68 = HNCS58+HNCS59+HNCS62-HNCS63+HNCS64+HNCS65+HNCS66+HNCS67; atemp['HNCS68'] = HNCS58+HNCS59+HNCS62-HNCS63+HNCS64+HNCS65+HNCS66+HNCS67; var H69 = H56+H68; atemp['H69'] = H56+H68; var HNCS69 = HNCS56+HNCS68; atemp['HNCS69'] = HNCS56+HNCS68; return JSON.stringify( atemp);} temp();
```

execute code:

```
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        Object result = null;
        try {
            Compilable compilable = (Compilable) engine;
            CompiledScript JSFunction = compilable.compile(script); 
            result=JSFunction.eval();
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

var script is 'js script code'.

error.log :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Failed generating bytecode for <eval>:1
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CompilationPhase$BytecodeGenerationPhase.transform(CompilationPhase.java:431)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CompilationPhase.apply(CompilationPhase.java:624)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:655)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.RecompilableScriptFunctionData.compileTypeSpecialization(RecompilableScriptFunctionData.java:725)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.RecompilableScriptFunctionData.getBest(RecompilableScriptFunctionData.java:905)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.getBest(ScriptFunctionData.java:375)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.getBestInvoker(ScriptFunctionData.java:237)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.findCallMethod(ScriptFunction.java:871)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptObject.lookup(ScriptObject.java:1825)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.NashornLinker.getGuardedInvocation(NashornLinker.java:104)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.NashornLinker.getGuardedInvocation(NashornLinker.java:98)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.CompositeTypeBasedGuardingDynamicLinker.getGuardedInvocation(CompositeTypeBasedGuardingDynamicLinker.java:176)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.CompositeGuardingDynamicLinker.getGuardedInvocation(CompositeGuardingDynamicLinker.java:124)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.LinkerServicesImpl.getGuardedInvocation(LinkerServicesImpl.java:154)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.createApplyOrCallCall(ScriptFunction.java:1058)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.findCallMethod(ScriptFunction.java:862)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptObject.lookup(ScriptObject.java:1825)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.NashornLinker.getGuardedInvocation(NashornLinker.java:104)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.NashornLinker.getGuardedInvocation(NashornLinker.java:98)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.CompositeTypeBasedGuardingDynamicLinker.getGuardedInvocation(CompositeTypeBasedGuardingDynamicLinker.java:176)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.CompositeGuardingDynamicLinker.getGuardedInvocation(CompositeGuardingDynamicLinker.java:124)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.support.LinkerServicesImpl.getGuardedInvocation(LinkerServicesImpl.java:154)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.DynamicLinker.relink(DynamicLinker.java:253)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$468$15$\^eval\_.temp(<eval>:1)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$467$\^eval\_.:program(<eval>:1)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:637)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:494)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:449)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.access$200(NashornScriptEngine.java:73)
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine$3.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:510)
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:106)
    at com.bwxy.pcsxm.accounting.common.utility.ScriptUtility.parseFunction(ScriptUtility.java:348)
    at com.bwxy.pcsxm.accounting.service.impl.report.ReportSheetServiceImpl.generateBalanceSheetBegin(ReportSheetServiceImpl.java:274)
    at com.bwxy.pcsxm.accounting.service.impl.report.ReportSheetServiceImpl.generateCashFlowStatement(ReportSheetServiceImpl.java:1883)
    at com.bwxy.pcsxm.accounting.service.impl.report.ReportSheetServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d4bbec24.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at com.bwxy.pcsxm.accounting.service.impl.report.ReportSheetServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5a86e337.generateCashFlowStatement(<generated>)
    at com.bwxy.pcsxm.accounting.service.impl.report.CashFlowServiceImpl.queryCashFlowStatement(CashFlowServiceImpl.java:96)
    at com.bwxy.pcsxm.accounting.service.impl.report.CashFlowServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b9c16bba.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at com.bwxy.pcsxm.accounting.service.impl.report.CashFlowServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7b9bf60d.queryCashFlowStatement(<generated>)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.common.bytecode.Wrapper33.invokeMethod(Wrapper33.java)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.proxy.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory$1.doInvoke(JavassistProxyFactory.java:46)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.proxy.AbstractProxyInvoker.invoke(AbstractProxyInvoker.java:72)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.InvokerWrapper.invoke(InvokerWrapper.java:53)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.ProtocolFilterWrapper$1.invoke(ProtocolFilterWrapper.java:91)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.monitor.support.MonitorFilter.invoke(MonitorFilter.java:65)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.ProtocolFilterWrapper$1.invoke(ProtocolFilterWrapper.java:91)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.filter.TimeoutFilter.invoke(TimeoutFilter.java:42)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.ProtocolFilterWrapper$1.invoke(ProtocolFilterWrapper.java:91)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.dubbo.filter.TraceFilter.invoke(TraceFilter.java:78)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.ProtocolFilterWrapper$1.invoke(ProtocolFilterWrapper.java:91)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.filter.ContextFilter.invoke(ContextFilter.java:70)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.ProtocolFilterWrapper$1.invoke(ProtocolFilterWrapper.java:91)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.filter.GenericFilter.invoke(GenericFilter.java:132)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.ProtocolFilterWrapper$1.invoke(ProtocolFilterWrapper.java:91)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.filter.ClassLoaderFilter.invoke(ClassLoaderFilter.java:38)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.ProtocolFilterWrapper$1.invoke(ProtocolFilterWrapper.java:91)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.filter.EchoFilter.invoke(EchoFilter.java:38)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.ProtocolFilterWrapper$1.invoke(ProtocolFilterWrapper.java:91)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.rpc.protocol.dubbo.DubboProtocol$1.reply(DubboProtocol.java:113)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.remoting.exchange.support.header.HeaderExchangeHandler.handleRequest(HeaderExchangeHandler.java:84)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.remoting.exchange.support.header.HeaderExchangeHandler.received(HeaderExchangeHandler.java:170)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.remoting.transport.DecodeHandler.received(DecodeHandler.java:52)
    at com.alibaba.dubbo.remoting.transport.dispatcher.ChannelEventRunnable.run(ChannelEventRunnable.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.BinaryNode.accept(BinaryNode.java:335)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CodeGenerator.loadExpression(CodeGenerator.java:857)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CodeGenerator.loadExpression(CodeGenerator.java:833)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CodeGenerator.loadAndDiscard(CodeGenerator.java:3663)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CodeGenerator.loadCOMMARIGHT(CodeGenerator.java:4155)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CodeGenerator.access$3300(CodeGenerator.java:178)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CodeGenerator$2.enterCOMMARIGHT(CodeGenerator.java:1079)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.visitor.NodeOperatorVisitor.enterBinaryNode(NodeOperatorVisitor.java:145)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.BinaryNode.accept(BinaryNode.java:335)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CodeGenerator.loadExpression(CodeGenerator.java:857)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CodeGenerator.loadExpression(CodeGenerator.java:833)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CodeGenerator.loadAndDiscard(CodeGenerator.java:3663)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CodeGenerator.loadCOMMARIGHT(CodeGenerator.java:4155)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CodeGenerator.access$3300(CodeGenerator.java:178)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CodeGenerator$2.enterCOMMARIGHT(CodeGenerator.java:1079)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.visitor.NodeOperatorVisitor.enterBinaryNode(NodeOperatorVisitor.java:145)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.BinaryNode.accept(BinaryNode.java:335)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CodeGenerator.loadExpression(CodeGenerator.java:857)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CodeGenerator.loadExpression(CodeGenerator.java:833)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CodeGenerator.loadAndDiscard(CodeGenerator.java:3663)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CodeGenerator.loadCOMMARIGHT(CodeGenerator.java:4155)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CodeGenerator.access$3300(CodeGenerator.java:178)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CodeGenerator$2.enterCOMMARIGHT(CodeGenerator.java:1079)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.visitor.NodeOperatorVisitor.enterBinaryNode(NodeOperatorVisitor.java:145)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this, your code runs fine on my machine.

Comment: Yep , the code runs fines on my local machine,but not worked in server machine, not often.

Comment: When the code runs on the server, it already has a bunch of calls (Spring, remoting, etc.) on the stack, so there's less space on the stack for the Nashorn stack frames. That's why it runs locally. It means this is not a problem with Nashorn, rather you need to increase the stack size on your server with the `-Xss` command line option.

Comment: It's really the problem. The   ```-Xss``` value is 128k, it's too low.  Thank you .@Attila Szegedi.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the solution to this is to increase your thread stack size:

```
-Xss256k
```

Or more...